# Doctrine Migration is only loading one record from CSV upload

Tags: php, csv, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am working in symfony 1.4 and Doctrine using a migration to upload data into a database.

I have a CSV file that I am trying to batch load into the sfGuardUser table, and also match the user id with the sfGuardUserGroup group id, and load that into the sf_guard_user table.

When I run the migration, it is only loading the first record from the CSV. The record that loads looks formatted correctly(building the username and dates).

I tested the code before putting it into the migration, and it worked correctly.

Do I have a syntax eror here, or is it not set up to loop correctly?

Maybe I have just bungled it up entirely.

**PHP**

```
    public function up()
      {

          $fieldseparator = ",";
          $lineseparator = "\n";
          $csvfile = "web/uploads/batchUpload.csv";

          $file = fopen($csvfile,"r");
          $size = filesize($csvfile);

          $csvcontent = fread($file,$size);

          fclose($file);

          $lines = 0;
          $queries = "";
          $linearray = array();

          foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {

              //Clean it up
              $lines++;   
              $line = trim($line," \t");      
              $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);      
              $line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);  
              $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);

              //build username
              if (!$linearray[3]) {
                  $username = $linearray[0];
                  $username = substr($linearray[0], 0, 1);
                  $username .= $linearray[1];
                  $username = strtolower($username);
                  $linearray[3] = $username;
              }

              //add sha1 algorithm
              if (!$linearray[4]) {
                  $linearray[4] = "sha1";
              }

              //add is_active
              if(!$linearray[7]) {
                  $linearray[7] = "1";
              }

              //add current date to login, created and updated
                  $now = getdate();           
                  if ($now['mday'] < 10) {
                      $now['mday'] = str_pad($now['mday'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                  }           
                  if ($now['hours'] < 10) {
                  $now['hours'] = str_pad($now['hours'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                  }       
                  if ($now['minutes'] < 10) {
                  $now['minutes'] = str_pad($now['minutes'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                  }       
                  if ($now['seconds'] < 10) {
                  $now['seconds'] = str_pad($now['seconds'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                  }
                  $linearray[10] = $now['year']. "-" .$now['mon']. 
                          "-".$now['mday']." ".$now['hours'].":".$now['minutes'].":"
                          .$now['seconds'];
                  $linearray[11] = $now['year']. "-" .$now['mon']. 
                          "-".$now['mday']. " ".$now['hours'].":".$now['minutes'].
                          ":".$now['seconds'];


             //load up sql  
             $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);    
             $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();  
             $query = "INSERT INTO sf_guard_user VALUES ('', '$linemysql');";

             //$queries .= $query . "\n";   
             $conn->execute($query);

             //Add userID to group table
             $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();  
             $getFirstID = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->orderBy('id DESC')
                  ->limit(1)->execute();
             $id = $getFirstID['id'];
             $query = "INSERT INTO sf_guard_user_group ('$id', 5, '$linearray[10]',          '$linearray[11]');";
             $conn->execute($query);
             $query = "INSERT INTO sf_guard_user_group ('$id', 14, '$linearray[10]', '$linearray[11]');";
             $conn->execute($query);
        }// close foreach split
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove the second query where I am trying to get the last id loaded and match it with the GuardUserGroup group_id, then it works. So I guess we can narrow it down and say my error is in the `//Add userID to group table` section

Comment: The copy/paste is right? Because you have an error, the line after `$linearray[10] = $now['year']. "-" .$now['mon'].` (according to the higlighted code)

Comment: That was a copy error, not in actual code. Trying to make the code a little more legible, than one long string. Code has been updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPdated my query to get the latest id record. I think the main issue was $id was still an array in the query. I broke it out like this:

```
//Add userID to group table
$getFirstID = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery()->select('MAX(id) as id')->fetchArray();
**$id = $getFirstID[0];
$id = $id['id'];**
$q = "INSERT INTO sf_guard_user_group VALUES ('$id', 5, '$linearray[10]', '$linearray[11]');";
$conn->execute($q);
$query = "INSERT INTO sf_guard_user_group VALUES ('$id', 14, '$linearray[10]', '$linearray[11]');";
$conn->execute($query);
```

Comment: So instead of $getFirstID = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery()->select('MAX(id) as id')->fetchArray(), it would be $getFirstID = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->createQuery()->select('MAX(id) as id')->fetchOne();?? Would that keep it from automatically loading into an array? I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: `fetchOne` is the same as `fetchArray` but it will retrieve only one element as an array. So, it's what you want.